# Question about generating Apple Passes in React front end

Tags: ios, reactjs, qr-code, passkit

I have a React front end that generates unique QR codes. I was wondering what is the easiest way to integrate Apple/Google Wallet into my application so that users can download this unique QR code into their wallet?

Would I need something like this: https://pkvd.app/